# Hiding Menu Item with CSS - will Google penalise my site?

Tags: css, hide, menuitem, submenu

I want to ask you about something.
I want to hide some sub menu items , using the css class, and assign it to the specific menu item.
For example the class is nodisplay

```
/* Hide menu items */
.nodisplay {
display:none !important;
}
```

This works great, but I wonder if this would be penalized by Google, as I read that Google don't like hidden texts? I read that Google marks this as spam, is it true not ?

I have a look at the Gavick Menus and Helix Menus, they are using display: none; or left:-999em; too for making the  elements.

So my dilemma is if I use display: none; for hiding all my sub level 3 menu items , will Google penalize my site or not ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will move my question to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SEO question, which you can ask here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Google will disregard anything that's not displaying. Remember that `Google` works with the source code not the outcome, so anything you do in your source code except server side, is public.

Even if they detect displaying blue words on blue background, Google will disregard that too or even punish for such technique.

Having a display:none is not so serious however, as we know that sometimes its use cannot be avoided. But sometimes there are better ways for swapping content than toggle() in jQ. Try to enhance your code to contain less or no non-displaying content, and it will be okay in `SEO POV`.

Rendering the page for the first time should return no non-displaying content, so Google will not detect a `black hat` trial. After that, you can do anything with `JS`, it wont affect SERP rankings.

Comment: Thanks Siyah for your answer. I asked this , because many drop-down menus are using this technique, that's why I was wonder . I will ask the question in the link you sent me.

Comment: No problem. If you can accept the answer, than we can close this topic.

Kolay gelsin.

Comment: Yes the answer is ok for me , and I already start new discussion about this topic here, as you suggested 
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/58238/hiding-menu-item-with-css-will-google-penalise-my-site

So we can close this topic